# Carrier app throws SecurityException when adding an APN

Tags: android, privileges, telecommunication, apn, euiccmanager

We have an eUICC with carrier privileges, we are able to check the privileges by

`telephonyManager.hasCarrierPrivileges()` and it returns **true**.

[Android documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/uicc#telephonyprovider) says that we are able to use the Content provider APIs to add, modify an APN.

But we are still unable to add the APNs. the stack trace

````
java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to access APN settings
        at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider.checkPermission(TelephonyProvider.java:7029)
        at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider.insertSingleRow(TelephonyProvider.java:5948) ```
````

Comment: were you able to get the reason and what was required to get this to work?